# Get GenericType-Name in good format using Reflection on C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to get the name of generic-type in form of its declaration in code.

For example:
For List<Int32> I want to get string "List<Int32>".
Standart property Type.Name returns "List`1" in this situation.

EDIT: example was fixed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I've done a bunch of research, and discovered that typeof(List) has "GetGenericArguments" which will get you the sub names.  So I'd do it this way (for 1 generic type, if it is a multi it'll take a loop or something.  I can post a function for that if requested.

Here is a function to do it with multiple generic arguments, handles 'nested' generic types.  Edited again to make this use the Aggregate function:

```
static string GetFullName(Type t)
{
    if (!t.IsGenericType)
        return t.Name;
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.LastIndexOf("`")));
    sb.Append(t.GetGenericArguments().Aggregate("<",

        delegate(string aggregate,Type type)
            {
                return aggregate + (aggregate == "<" ? "" : ",") + GetFullName(type);
            }  
        ));
    sb.Append(">");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Should be enhanced a bit. The generic argument should be formatted the same way, it could be a generic type again. Of course it should support many generic arguments.

Comment: I was in the process of typing a more complex version which handled that and multiples, which I just posted.

Comment: Edited again to use aggregates.  Check the edit history if you want the 'old' version.  Functionality is identical, but I wanted to figure out how aggregate worked, and this was a good way to learn :)

Comment: When you already use a stringbuilder, you might just as well use it in your aggregate call:

    sb.Append(t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.LastIndexOf("`")));
    int i = 0
    t.GetGenericArguments()
     .Aggregate(sb,
                (a, type) =>
                 a.Append((i++ == 0 ? "<" : ",")
                  .Append(GetFullName(type)));

Comment: See [CaringDev's simpler answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287378/199364)

Comment: Probably better to use string concatenation here.  StringBuilder is for when the number of concatenations is indeterminate or dynamic.  Were you to pass it down through the recursion, that would be a case for it.

Answer (score 19):

Using built-in functions and Linq this can be written

```
static string PrettyTypeName(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsArray)
    {
        return PrettyTypeName(t.GetElementType()) + "[]";
    }

    if (t.IsGenericType)
    {
        return string.Format(
            "{0}<{1}>",
            t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.LastIndexOf("`", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)),
            string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(PrettyTypeName)));
    }

    return t.Name;
}
```

NOTE: In pre-4.0 versions of C#, `string.Join` requires explicit `.ToArray()`:

```
string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(PrettyTypeName).ToArray()));
```

Comment: In VS 2010 with .NET 3.5 (not sure which C# version), `t.GetGenericArguments().Select(PrettyTypeName)` gives compiler error "*cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'*"  Fix: append `.ToArray()`.  Adding to answer as an alternative.

Comment: Not working for `PrettyTypeName(typeof(ICollection<Tuple<string, int, Tuple<ICollection<string>,IList>[]>[]>))`. `if (t.IsArray) return PrettyTypeName(t.GetElementType()) + "[]";` must be added.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't too hard. ;-)

Okay, I'll bite... *g* The one below works recusively and displays primitive types w/o namespace (like the OP wrote):

```
  static string PrettyPrintGenericTypeName(Type typeRef)
  {
     var rootType = typeRef.IsGenericType
        ? typeRef.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        : typeRef;

     var cleanedName = rootType.IsPrimitive
                          ? rootType.Name
                          : rootType.ToString();

     if (!typeRef.IsGenericType)
        return cleanedName;
     else
        return cleanedName.Substring(0,
                                     cleanedName.LastIndexOf('`'))
            + typeRef.GetGenericArguments()
                     .Aggregate("<",
                                (r, i) =>
                                   r
                                   + (r != "<" ? ", " : null)
                                   + PrettyPrintGenericTypeName(i))
            + ">";
  }
```

The resulting cleanedName looks like this: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Collections.Generic.List<Int32>, ConsoleApplication2.Program+SomeType>`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I only have the need for this today. So I wrote an extension method that can output nice looking C#-formatted generic name that can handle multilevel nested generic types.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string GetNiceName(this Type type, bool useFullName = false)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericType) {
            return type.Name;
        }

        var typeNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        GetNiceGenericName(typeNameBuilder, type, useFullName);
        return typeNameBuilder.ToString();
    }

    static void GetNiceGenericName(StringBuilder sb, Type type, bool useFullName)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericType) {
            sb.Append(useFullName ? type.FullName : type.Name);
            return;
        }

        var typeDef = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var typeName = useFullName ? typeDef.FullName : typeDef.Name;
        sb.Append(typeName);
        sb.Length -= typeName.Length - typeName.LastIndexOf('`');
        sb.Append('<');
        foreach (var typeArgument in type.GenericTypeArguments) {
            GetNiceGenericName(sb, typeArgument, useFullName);
            sb.Append(", ");
        }
        sb.Length -= 2;
        sb.Append('>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't remove the namespace names, just say:

```
Regex.Replace(""+@type, @"`\d+\[", "<").Replace("]", ">");
```

and if you do, say:

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(""+@type, @"`\d+\[", "<").Replace("]", ">"), @"\w+\.", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example I just wrote myself before stumbling here.

```
    private string PrettyPrintGenericTypeName(Type p)
    {
        if (p.IsGenericType) {
            var simpleName = p.Name.Substring(0, p.Name.IndexOf('`'));
            var genericTypeParams = p.GenericTypeArguments.Select(PrettyPrintGenericTypeName).ToList();
            return string.Format("{0}<{1}>", simpleName, string.Join(", ", genericTypeParams));
        } else {
            return p.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago and i have written my own extension method.

This code works with normal types and "nullable reference types".

I'm not 100% shure that it works correctly in all cases but types like this works fine:

```
public IDictionary<MyClass?[][], Dictionary<object?,int?[,]?>>? Dummy { get; set; }
```

This works almost perfect for my needs:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static string ToReadableTypeString(this PropertyInfo property, bool useFullnames = false, bool useInternalTypeNames= true)
    {
        return ToReadableTypeStringInternal(property.PropertyType, new NullabilityInfoContext().Create(property), useFullnames, useInternalTypeNames);
    }

    public static string ToReadableTypeString(this Type type, NullabilityInfo? nullabilityInfo = null, bool useFullnames = false, bool useInternalTypeNames= true)
    {
        return ToReadableTypeStringInternal(type, nullabilityInfo, useFullnames, useInternalTypeNames);
    }

    private static string ToReadableTypeStringInternal(Type type,NullabilityInfo? nullabilityInfo, bool useFullnames, bool useInternalTypeNames)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        }

        string suffix;

        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

        if (underlyingType != null)
        {
            type = underlyingType;
            suffix = "?";
        }
        else
        {
            suffix = nullabilityInfo?.ReadState == NullabilityState.Nullable ? "?" : "";
        }

        if (useInternalTypeNames)
        {
            if (type == typeof(string)) { return "string"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(sbyte)) { return "sbyte"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(byte)) { return "byte"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(short)) { return "short"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(ushort)) { return "ushort"+suffix; } 
            if (type == typeof(int  )) { return "int"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(uint)) { return "uint"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(long)) { return "long"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(ulong )) { return "ulong"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(nint )) { return "nint"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(nuint)) { return "nuint"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(float)) { return "float"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(double)) { return "double"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(decimal)) { return "decimal"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(bool)) { return "bool"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(char)) { return "char"+suffix; }
            if (type == typeof(object)) { return "object"+suffix; }
        }
        
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(ToReadableTypeStringInternal(type.GetElementType()!, nullabilityInfo?.ElementType, useFullnames, useInternalTypeNames));

            if (type.IsVariableBoundArray)
            {
                sb.Append('[');
                sb.Append(new string(',',type.GetArrayRank()-1));
                sb.Append(']');
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < type.GetArrayRank(); i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("[]");
                }
            }
            
            return sb+suffix;
        }
        
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            return (useFullnames?(type.FullName??type.Name):type.Name).Split("`").First() + "<" + string.Join(",", type.GenericTypeArguments.Select((type1,index) => ToReadableTypeStringInternal(type1,nullabilityInfo?.GenericTypeArguments[index], useFullnames, useInternalTypeNames))) + ">";
        }

        return (useFullnames?(type.FullName??type.Name):type.Name)+suffix;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's because the name of the type in .NET actually IS List'1. The "'1" is the so called arity of the generic, and it tells you how many type parameters there are.

It's needed so that you can create more then 1 generic type with the same "name" but a different number of generic type parameters.

For example, there are more than 1 type "called" System.Action. The real names of these are System.Action'1, System.Action'2, System.Action'3 etc.

So, if you know that your type is generic, you can assume that there is this 'XX at the end of the name, so you could just cut this part away, for example like this:

```
string strTypeName = typeof(List<>).Name.Substring(0, typeof(List<>).Name.LastIndexOf("`"));
```

PS: Please replace ' with `.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my example. I need to get argument of generic type (in my example: Int32)

Comment: This answer is not relevant any more (after the question was edited).