# C# Get name of generic class via `nameof`

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class StateMachine<TTag> where TTag : Enum { ... }
```

Which logs using `Log` that accepts as first argument `string` tag. I use `nameof` with `StateMachine<TTag>` as an argument:

```
_logger.Log(nameof(StateMachine<TTag>), ...)
```

In my app I have instances of `StateMachine<TTag>`, like `StateMachine<AppStateTag>`, etc.

And I want my `StateMachine` to log like this:

```
StateMachine<AppStateTag> ...
```

But instead I get:

```
StateMachine ...
```

Do I need to get weird like this?

```
${nameof(StateMachine)}<{nameof(TTag)}>
```

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: @PaulKaram not exactly, but I've managed to get something out of those answers

Comment: You may be interested in [Get generic type name in good format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533115/get-generictype-name-in-good-format-using-reflection-on-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

So, ok, using answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898048/c-sharp-nameof-generic-type-without-specifying-type), I've managed to frankenstein this:

```
$"{nameof(StateMachine<TTag>)}<{typeof(TTag).Name}>"
```

If anyone can suggest a better way of doing this, it would be very much appreciated.